# Elliptic equation on riemannian manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry

Let $ M $ be a compact Riemannian manifold with or without boundary) and let $ \Delta $ be the metric laplacian. I want to study the differential operator $ -\Delta +q $ where $ q $ is a smooth function on $ M $. Now the first thing to do is a development of the theory of weak solutions for this differential operator. I think that all existence results in Chapter 6 , paragraph 2 of Evans' book 'Partial differentail equation' can be reformulate without changement for our case if we are able to prove the Poincarè inequality in the setting of a compact Riemannian manifold. Therefore the first question is

is the poincare inequality true for a compact riannian manifold with boundary?
(i think so)

Now the second problem is the proof of the well- known regularity theorem in our setting (chapter 6.3 of Evans book). Can anyone suggest me a good reference for it? I know the Aubin book but it seems not so clear at this point.\

Thanks

Comment: For Poincare, look at Hebey's _Nonlinear analysis on Manifolds_. For elliptic regularity, you have a linear operator which you can write in local coordinates. Have you checked to see if the stuff that's in Gilbarg and Trudinger cannot be applied?

Comment: Have you looked in Taylor's PDE bible?

Comment: Taylor's book is the reference that i'm looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to assume that $q \geq 0$, then this problem has been extensively studied by [Mitrea and Taylor](http://www.math.missouri.edu/~marius/mmitrea_MT9.pdf) (cf. also the references therein for their other papers on this topic that go back to 1999). If you want $q$ to be an arbitrary smooth function, then I doubt that there is any comprehensive study to date.